# How to use a JQuery Selector to find a DOM Element based on one of its multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

My direct/exact question can be found at the very bottom. The following is a bit of background info/ explanation.

So I've got this jQuery function written up in TS

```
    startEventListeners = () => {
        $(document).ready(() => {
            $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on('click', function (e) {
                $(this).next('ul').toggle();
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    };
```

And it's purpose is to open up sub-menu items in a drop down list, and that looks like this

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                New
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Blank Template <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">As Library Template</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">For This Use Only</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Copy of... <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu" ng-repeat="options in $ctrl.templateLookup.data">
                            <a class="test" href="#">{{options.key}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">As Library Template</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">For This Use Only</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And it's going well up until I get to these two lines

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu" ng-repeat="options in $ctrl.templateLookup.data">
<a class="test" href="#">{{options.key}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

My jquery selector is looking specifically for the classes, "dropdown-menu" and "test"

Because I'm using angular which is doing its job, no problems there; some classes are getting injected into those two lines and turning them into this

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu ng-scope" ng-repeat="options in $ctrl.templateLookup.data">
<a class="test ng-binding" href="#">{{options.key}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

So now my jquery selector can't find them. And I would just change the selector to search for .dropdown-submenu.ng-scope, and .test.ng-binding, but there's two other locations that use dropdown-submenu, and test, but don't use any angular so then my selector wouldn't find them.

After that mouthful of background info (sorry) my question is this.

Is there a way to format my jquery selector to find the DOM element I need it to find not based on its complete class, i.e. .dropdown-submenu.ng-scope, but off of just one of its multiple classes?

Comment: having another class is not preventing jQuery to select your element, so the problem is elsewhere. Do you have your code somewhere we can look at (e.g. codepen, plunker)? @Wikster2014

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban that is definitely unfortunate to hear. No I don't have the code anywhere, but the only code involved in the drop down is what I pasted into my question.

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban I actually realized the object being repeated on wasn't metnioned, my apologies. It's a array with a single index and it contains two properties at it's first and only index. A key holding a string value that = 'Standard Template' and a value property of type number that = 1

Comment: I can see that is inside ng-repeat which means you will have multiple elements selected by that selector, however if by the time the page renders your ng-repeat is not finished you will end up some or all of the items click handler not bound, if you share your controller code maybe I can reproduce it somewhere to see what is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try something like this

```
$('document').on('click','.dropdown-submenu, a.test',function( e ){  })
```

This should register ANY click events and validate it against the selectors at the time of the event rather than watching for a pre build list that may not yet exist.

After you do this you could have the regular e.stopPropagation(); and e.preventDefault(); in the function and just take action using $( this ) that way you can single out the dom element that you clicked on.

Comment: adding a comma won't help because now the click handler is bounded to both ul and a tags @LucasShanley

Comment: Give a try to something like this maybe:

Comment: The second bit got it! I think you're right I was probably calling watch on something that wasn't there yet, putting the watch on the event as it occurred and checking against the selectors got the exact behaviour I needed! Thanks so much!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I was able to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion, your problem relates to http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

try changing your code to the following:

```
startEventListeners = () => {
    $(document).ready(() => {
        $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-submenu a.test', function (e) {
            $(this).next('ul').toggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
};
```

this will allow those repeated elements (created by Angular **after** your `$(document).ready` have been executed) to get the delegated `click` event too

PS: the change is only for the `click` line